# How to round the courners of a UIImageView in a tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to have the uiimagview have rounded corners in a tableviewcell with this code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HomepwnerItemCell *cell = (HomepwnerItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];    

    Possession *possession = [self.possessions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.valueLabel.text = [@"$" stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:possession.valueInDollars] stringValue]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = possession.possessionName;

    UIImage *image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] imageForKey:possession.imageKey];      
    UIImageView *roundedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    roundedImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    roundedImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    cell.imageView = roundedImage;
    // cell.imageView.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] imageForKey:possession.imageKey];
    return cell;
}
```

but the images show up blank in the tableViewCells when I run it.

it works fine if I just do `cell.imageView.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] imageForKey:possession.imageKey];` (but without the rounded corners)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cell.imageView = [roundedImage Image]; Try this.

Comment: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'UIImageView' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'Image'

Comment: Check if the UIImage *image is allocated memory or not?

Comment: Unless you have not pasted your method above in its entirety, you need to fix your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: code first before worrying about rounded corners. Nowhere in it you are allocating new cells if a reusable one is not available??

Comment: new in ios5: "If there is no existing cell that can be recycled, dequeueReuseableCell will automatically make a new copy of the prototype cell and return it to you."

Comment: Good stuff, wasn't aware of that and take back my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YOu need to use the quartz framework. Here is the code for cornering and adding border to image

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.2;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

First Set Image to imageview, then change the imageview layer

Comment: but I have `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: are you able to see the image without the "corner" code. what are dimentions of the image you are setting

Comment: ah this worked, apparently I just need to set the image first before I change the imageview layer.

Comment: cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = [cell.imageView.image size].height /2; //gives you a rounded image.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20;  //Use as ur specified corner length
```

also implement

```
  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```